# Detecting Excel scroll in VBA

Tags: excel, events, scroll, vba

I read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm) by Mr Pearson saying that the excel object model doesn't allow detecting when the user scrolls and that in order to do so, we'll need to install some third party dlls, etc...

Is this still true in Excel 2010? The macro recorder seems to detect scrolling and prints the scrolling location to the subroutine as you scroll around the sheet (in fact you can see it doing this in real-time if you have the module visible while you scroll)... Surely there must be a way to do this if the macro recorder is doing it without installing other dlls?

Example code generated by macro recorder:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 16
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 17
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 18
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 19
```

Comment: "Surely there must be a way to do this if the macro recorder" - why? The macro recorder isn't written in VBA. It is possible to hook the Excel window and intercept the scroll messages using API calls but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is this still true in Excel 2010?* **Yes.** Listening to or handling **Events** for window scrolling is not intrinsic to the VBA environment within Excel 2010.

Assigning a value to a **Property** or invoking a **Method** are quite different from "hooking" or "listening" for an **Event**. In order to access any **Event**, **Method**, or **Property** of the Excel application or its child objects they must be exposed intrinsically by the VBA environment or through the use of Windows APIs.