# Problem with floating button in VBA - getting errors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to implement a button in an exceldocument that is supposed to float in the excel sheet. Always beeing visable in the upper left corner even if I scroll down or sideways.

I have tried various versions of the code below.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
         On Error GoTo 0
         With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
             R1.Top = .Top + 100
             R1.Left = .Left + 300
         End With
 End Sub
```

When running the code I get an error message "424"

Comment: Where is `R1` defined?

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
        .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
End Sub
```

[Credit](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013544_Creating_a_Floating_Macro_Button.html)

Answer (score 0):

First: Your runtime occurs because `R1` is not a valid object variable. As Chrismas007 writes in his answer, use something like `With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")` (replace the string with the name of your button) to access the button within VBA.

Second: The Event `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will be triggered every time a cell is selected in Excel. However, when you scroll, you don't change the selected cell, so the event is not fired until you click into the sheet (or the field where you can enter the value). If you can live with that, try

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
    Dim topcell As Range
    Set topcell = Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
    .top = topcell.top + 100
    .left = topcell.left + 100
End With
```

You will notice that the button will disappear when you scroll, and reappears when you click into a cell.

The optimal solution would be to react to the `Scroll`-Event, however, Excel-VBA doesn't expose this event (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069113/7599798). I found a page which seems to offer a solution (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm), but haven't had a close look into it.